# Why did Yukine stop stinging Yato?

Tags: noragami

Some people are unable to control their natural urges, so if Yukine was thinking that way and stung Yato, why is it after the whole issue he stopped stinging? And if he continues to feel that way, what then will happen to Yato?

How did the stinging just stop?

Answer (score 1):

well, he basically learned his lesson; his character changed a lot after the whole incident (Hiyori helping him afterwards is a big reason too); He is, afterall a teenage boy~

if he would continue to "sting" Yato... [Spoilers avoided] (you should see season 2 if you haven't already, since it covers that in the anime with Bishamon)